# How to mock an object which is inside the method of serviceimpl class

Tags: java, unit-testing

code looks something like this

```
public GetPortfoliosResponse retrievePortfolios(RequestIdentityInfo requestIdentityInfo, GetPortfoliosRequest getPortfoliosRequest) {
    PortfolioReferenceParameter portfolioReferenceParameter = new PortfolioReferenceParameter();
    //some code
    List<Portfolio> portfolios = portfolioReferenceParameter.getPortfolios();
}
```

and in my test class I am doing something like this

```
@Mock
private PortfolioReferenceParameter portfolioReferenceParameter;
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    List<Portfolio> portfolios = new ArrayList<Portfolio>();
    //code to build the list
    when(portfolioReferenceParameter.getPortfolios()).thenReturn(portfolios);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

When I make a call to the serviceimpl method it is still taking the actual object of PortfolioReferenceParameter which is locally created in that method. How can I mock that object with my object?

Comment: I think that in the productive program the portfolios are filled, correct? In this case your test does things that will never occur in productive scenario. You should better mock the true sources of the portfolio list.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking constructors is not supported in Mockito - you will need to use PowerMock `whenNew` for that - see https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13.

A better way would be to refactor your retrievePortfolios method to take an instance of PortfolioReferenceParameter as an argument and inject the mock in your test

```
public class AppTest {

    @Mock
    private PortfolioReferenceParameter referenceParam;

    private List portfolios = new ArrayList();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(referenceParam.getPortfolios())
          .thenReturn(portfolios);
    }

    @Test
    public void testApp() {
        GetPortfoliosResponse response = retrievePortfolios(requestIdentityInfo, getPortfoliosRequest, referenceParam);
        // assert response details
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the serviceImpl code. I guess I need togo with the PowerMock as you are saying. Thanks for that